# in pyqt5 with matpoltlib, how to change the scatter3d background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

How to change the axes background color?

[image]

In this URL link image, I would like to change the color in the axes, but not background color.

My code is:

```
self.ui.img.canvas.axes = self.ui.img.canvas.figure.add_subplot(projection='3d', facecolor=(.18, .31, .31))
self.ui.img.canvas.axes.set_facecolor('#eafff5')
```

Upon the above code the property Facecolor changed background but it's not my requirement( I need to change axes color)

Is anyone know how to fix my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what `edgecolor` is? Seems to be the only other color thing in the docs at https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html

Comment: hi antont, it's not edgecolor. my plot is Axes3DSubplot, and no edgecolor or I could not find it....